# Android share apk issue_the file format is not supported

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send apk through application which have capability to send applications, I tested all the answers but I get this toast message.
**the file format is not supported**,,,,

**this is my the code that I have test**

```
public  void shareApp() {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        Uri path = Uri.parse("/data/apps/"+getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".apk");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Here is the fancy app");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Don't miss it!");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share via"));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
           Toast.makeText(getContext(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }}
```

Comment: That's not a valid `Uri`. A `Uri` has a scheme, for starters.

Comment: A scheme such as `file:` which is forbidden starting Android 7 so good luck using this method. Plus the file often has a postfix such as `-2`. Find another way.

Comment: thank you ,i have  try many codes. and all gives me the same message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Share Entire Android App with Share Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941093/how-to-share-entire-android-app-with-share-intent)