# How to share an android application with intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to share my app through every possible installed apps on user device..
I mean my apk file itself not just a link of my app .. 
how can I do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Share Entire Android App with Share Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941093/how-to-share-entire-android-app-with-share-intent)

Comment: @ArunElectra I already saw, That is about sharing text not a file

Comment: Plese try my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First of all, SO is not a developer on hire service. You should try
>   something, and then if you hit a roadblock, then ask here for
>   help,describing your problem.

**Edit 2**

Found another piece of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25982697/2319627)

```
try {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    File srcFile = new File(ai.publicSourceDir);
    Intent share = new Intent();
    share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(srcFile));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "PersianCoders"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ShareApp", e.getMessage());
}
```

**Edit**

Try this code (From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984988/how-to-send-apk-using-share-intent-programatically-in-android))

```
ArrayList<Uri> arrayListapkFilepath; // define global

            //put this code when you wants to share apk
            arrayListapkFilepath = new ArrayList<Uri>();

            shareAPK(getPackageName());
            // you can pass bundle id of installed app in your device instead of getPackageName()
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    arrayListapkFilepath);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share " +
                    arrayListapkFilepath.size() + " Files Via"));

//Method
public void shareAPK(String bundle_id) {
    File f1;
    File f2 = null;

    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    final List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    int z = 0;
    for (Object object : pkgAppsList) {

        ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) object;
        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.equals(bundle_id)) {

            f1 = new File(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);

            Log.v("file--",
                    " " + f1.getName().toString() + "----" + info.loadLabel(getPackageManager()));
            try {

                String file_name = info.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
                Log.d("file_name--", " " + file_name);

                f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Folder");
                f2.mkdirs();
                f2 = new File(f2.getPath() + "/" + file_name + ".apk");
                f2.createNewFile();

                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);

                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);

                // byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                out.close();
                System.out.println("File copied.");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    arrayListapkFilepath.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(f2.getAbsolutePath())));

}
```

**Old Answer**
To answer your question, it is not possible to share your "apk" through "app through every possible installed apps" for obvious reasons. Of-course You can write code to share your apk through bluetooth or LAN Wifi, and, you could attach your apk to a mail/supported messaging services. But it is not possible to do as "you put that".

You can copy your apk to some place by using this code

```
File file = new File(getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).publicSourceDir);
// Copy the .apk file to wherever
```

And you can share it using Bluetooth/Wifi/Intent with ACTION_SEND by attaching the apk you saved/copied. But as far as I know, very few messagin apps permits sending apk files.

This [Article](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-connection-example-part-ii-tcp-communication) will help you in sharing files :

Comment: Can I change ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE to just ACTION_SEND in this method without losing valid content ?

Comment: Yes, you can as long as you are sending only one file.

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: Yes , It works .. actually I tried this answer before I ask my own question but I had problem with ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE .. this will reduce apps that are capable of sharing my application..

Comment: @DastakWall have you tried the latest update?

NB : If my answer helped, please accept it and upvote :-)

Comment: I appreciate your help , sure